# Mobile Website Issues (Whitespace & Zooming)

Tags: html, css, mobile, joomla

Hello I have been trying to make my website look good on mobile as it does on a computer but am running into a few issues. The first is that when you access my website on a mobile or tablet device it comes up very enlarged and zoomed in.

http://www.questdesign.com.au

Is there anyway to make it start zoomed out so you get to see all the content and users can zoom in if they prefer.

The second issue is the white space that you can see at the bottom of the page. I have looked all through the coding and can't see what I have done wrong.

My css is below,

http://questdesign.com.au/templates/protostar/css/template.css

Thanks for any advise or help.

Answer (score 0):

you need utilize the media queries more. you can use chrome to check how your website looks on various mobile screens also.

Right-click inspect elements, on left had side corner you'll see an icon shaped as a phone, click on that, this will render you website, as to how it would look on your phone or tablet, use this with your media queries.

Hope this helps